# Date time conversion in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Am trying to convert 2021-03-31 20:44:01 to 03/31/2021 20:44:01 in pandas. I tried dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y")  and it converts to mm/dd/yyyy but am not sure how to retain the timestamp part. I tried dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H%M%S") but it is not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H%M%S")
```

Use:

```
dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
```

**For example:**

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2021-03-31 20:44:01','2021-04-01 10:22:55']})
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
print(df)

    Date
0   03/31/21 20:44:01
1   04/01/21 10:22:55
```